# C# htmlagilitypack Node.InnerHTML not case correct, how to pull case correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack and i'm using the standard operating procedure for loading a document and select a node.  However when i go to view the node all the aspx controls are in lowercase.  is there a way to get it in propercase  For example  when I look at `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator` it's returned as `<asp:requiredfieldvalidator`.  This wont work because i'm mass updating my controls.

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc.Load(@"C:\my.ascx");
        HtmlNodeCollection node_collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
foreach (HtmlNode node in node_collection)
        {
           templateString = node.InnerHtml; //lower case happens here.....
        }
```

Anybody?

Comment: Side note: HtmlAgilityPack parses HTML, ascx does not necessary contain valid HTML and may not even contain tags...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov which i understand but you would think it wouldnt format text

Comment: It normalizes tags (like `<HtMl>` should be `<html>`) - so while not necessary correct to lowercase namespaced nodes, HtmlAgilityPack have some reason to do so for all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to set true to `OptionOutputOriginalCase` before `Load`

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionOutputOriginalCase = true;

doc.LoadHtml("<html><asp:RequiredFieldValidator></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></html>");

var html = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionOutputOriginalCase = true;
doc.LoadHtml("<html><asp:Content ID='Content1' ContentPlaceHolderID='head'     runat='Server'/></html>");
var html = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but you need to be more clear. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)